# Need to dump a unicode into a .json but i get unicodeescape error

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, unicode

I am trying to save in a .json a string and it has to have the following format "\uXXXX" but i get the unicodeescape error:

```
(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

Doing a raw string doesn't work, because I can't get a string like this as a result: "\\uXXXX".

This is what im trying:

```
import json

bp = {"type": "bitmap",
                "file": "file",
                "chars": [f"\u{hex(57392)[2:].upper()}"]
                }
with open(dir, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(bp, f, indent = 4)
```

And i try to get:

```
{
"type": "bitmap",
"file": "file:,
"chars": ["\uE030"]
}
```

I only want to generate the JSON, im not loading it afterwards.

Is there any way to save the string in the format I need?

Comment: show a [mcve] with the string and saving attempt.

Comment: That error is from writing an invalid unicode escape sequence in a string literal. Using a raw string or escaping the backslash is the correct thing to do. Could you clarify why you think that isn't working? Are you perhaps confusing the `repr()` representation of a string (what gets printed when you evaluate an expression at the interactive prompt) with it's contents?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make the example clear by showing exactly: 1) What is the data that you want to save? (Make sure this is unambigous, by saying, for example "I have a text file that contains this:" or "I have a string variable in my program that I made with this code:" etc.) 2) What should be in the file afterwards, when you view it in a text editor?

Comment: "the following format "\uEXXX"" - **what does this mean**? What is the `E`? Should that always be an uppercase capital E, or is that some kind of placeholder? What rule should we use to understand the format? For example, if the file contains `\uE123`, is that allowed? What will it represent, if so? What is special about the E?

Comment: To be clear with the updated example: you want to see the **exact text** `"\uE030"` **when you open the JSON file in a text editor**; and when you load the JSON, you want that to represent a string with the `` symbol?

Comment: Yes, i want the exact text, and im not going to load the JSON, im only generating it

Answer (score 0):

Use `chr` to get the correct Unicode character, instead of trying to construct a Python escape sequence dynamically.

```
bp = {"type": "bitmap",
      "file": "file",
      "chars": [chr(57392)]
     }
```

By default, `json.dump` will encode non-ASCII strings using `\u....` escapes, rather than UTF-8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

The `json` standard library automatically escapes the data in strings that are passed to it, when it writes the file with `json.dump` (or creates the string with `json.dumps`) - it **has to, because the JSON file format requires that**. It is **not valid JSON**, for example, if the file says something like `{"bad": "\"}`. So if the input dictionary is `{'bad': '\\'}` (i.e., the value contains **one** backslash, which is **represented as** two in the source code), then the output JSON will show two backslashes in the actual file.

Similarly with Unicode escapes. If the file should contain `"\ue030"`, then the input string should contain **the actual character** represented by this escape sequence - for example, the source code could contain a string literal with that actual text (`''`), or the source code could itself use an escape sequence (`'\ue030'`).

Uppercase vs. lowercase **does not matter**; it means **the same thing** when the file is read by a proper JSON tool. In fact, a valid JSON file can contain either the character or the escape sequence, too. It means the same thing.

**By default, `json` will already** choose to use the escape sequence when it writes out the data. (To make it put Unicode text in the file instead, pass `ensure_ascii=False`.)

It is **not possible to "construct"** an escape sequence by "joining" for example `'\u'` with `'e030'`, because `'\u'` **is invalid on its own**. Interpreting the escape sequences in string literals in the Python code, happens **before** any operations like joining strings together.

To turn a number into the corresponding Unicode code point, use `chr`.

Let's demonstrate at the REPL:

```
>>> import json
>>> bp = {"type": "bitmap",
...                 "file": "file",
...                 "chars": [chr(57392)]
...                 }
>>> 
>>> print(json.dumps(bp, indent=4))
{
    "type": "bitmap",
    "file": "file",
    "chars": [
        "\ue030"
    ]
}
```

Again: we do not get to control the `e` being lowercase, and we do not need to. It means the same thing when the file is read.